# How do I get past these balls that are being blown?

Tags: badland

Right now I'm a bit stuck in Day II -  Blow. 
I think I'm about half way through the level, but I'm completely flummoxed as to how to get past this obstacle:

[image: the obstacle]

I can't seem to maneuver above these balls without being crushed, and I can't seem to keep my momentum when trying to go under the balls.

**How do I get past this obstacle?**

Answer (score 1):

According to [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FnYLll9Romc&t=54), you need to have two or more avatars and just fly across the top of the obstacle.

To get multiple avatars (shown in the video) get multiple tiny ones with the grey power ups
[image: location of grey power ups]

Then, after being sucked along and losing some avatars, resize your remaining avatars with the yellow power ups.

[image: location of yellow power ups]

Comment: The checkpoint is right before, so multiple avatars isn't the solution.

Comment: Yeah the screencap I took was of my little avatar sitting at the checkpoint, since I was stuck at this obstacle. I didn't have much momentum or access to clones at that point.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a better answer at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really give a definitive strategy, but can offer some suggestions.  I've had success going both over and under.  I think the best tip that I can give is to try and push the balls over to the right, and then go under.  This technique isn't 100%, but it does seem to work for me at least some of the time.  What has also worked is just blind luck.